# JQuery - Replacing a background-image for another on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to replace a background image with another background image on click. Eventually I would like to be able to toggle the image on and off by clicking the image.

HTML

```
     <div class="arrow-up" role="button"></div><div class="arrow-down" role="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-up {
width: 15px;
height: 14px;
background-image: url("//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/b3vXuNpkEkQVRIBnRfoVOgBmT-5X4BEnyMoP85J2QIg.png")!important;
background-position: center center;
border: none!important;
}

.arrow-down {
margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 14px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 15px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
outline: none;
}
.arrow-down {
width: 15px;
height: 14px;
background-image: url("//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/b3vXuNpkEkQVRIBnRfoVOgBmT-5X4BEnyMoP85J2QIg.png")!important;
background-position: center center;
border: none!important;
}
.arrow-up {
margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 14px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 15px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
outline: none;
}
.arrow-down {
background-position: -30px -24px!important;
}
.arrow-down {
background-image: url(sprite-reddit.ZDiVRxCXXWg.png);
background-position: 0px -865px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.arrow-up {
background-position: 0px -24px!important;
}
```

JQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
$(".arrow-up").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "http://i.imgur.com/rySpqwS.jpg");
});
});
```

Would I be able to toggle the image like this? Because this solution doesn't seem to function.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".arrow-up").click(function () {
 if  ($(this).css("background-image") ==      "//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/b3vXuNpkEkQVRIBnRfoVOgBmT-5X4BEnyMoP85J2QIg.png")
 {
 $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://imgur.com/dpvAtIb.jpg)")
 }
 else {
  $(this).css("background-image", "url(//b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/b3vXuNpkEkQVRIBnRfoVOgBmT-5X4BEnyMoP85J2QIg.png)")
 }
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct CSS value for a background-image is `url(image)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".arrow-up").click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-image", "url(http://i.imgur.com/rySpqwS.jpg)");
    });
});
```

Note that javascript won't be able to set the background image, as it's set with `!important` in the CSS, and `!important` overwrites inline styles, so you won't see any change until you remove `!important` from your styles.
Using `!important` generally means you've failed miserably at something, it's not something you should use on all your styles.

Comment: Thank you! also, do you know how to style that image once it's there? for instance background size?

Comment: Sure, it's the same thing, i.e. `$(this).css("background-size", "cover");`

Comment: Can you take a look at the latest edit I made to my post? it doesn't want to work when it comes to toggling the image on and off

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm - `$(this).css("background-image")` probably also returns something liks `url(image)`, try logging it to the console, and see what you get.